# How to send excel file as an attachment in email in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my excel file in public folder.
Heres the directory structure

[image]

The file name is user_products.xlsx.
I need to send it as an attachment.
Here is the mail class's build function

```
public function build()
{
    // dd($this->data);
    return $this->subject('Subject:User Cart Inquiry')->view('emails.sendUserSubmitMail')
    ->attach(public_path('user_products.xlsx'), [
        'as' => 'user products.xlsx',
        'mime' => 'application/xlsx',
    ])
    ->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

The mail is working fine, but when i added the `->attach()`, its showing error.
The error is

```
message: "Unable to open file for reading [/opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/user_products.xlsx]"
```

Please help. Thank You!

Comment: dont know what happen, but you try to give 777 permission on this file `user_products.xlsx`

Comment: Oh maybe i should change the permission, and also what should be the MIME type?

Comment: this can be an issue with mime type too, for xlsx `'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never give 777 permission on production. Try this.

```
# sudo adduser $USER www-data
# sudo chown $USER:www-data -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
# sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

And now change the details in apache.

```
# sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

to this

```
User username
Group www-data
```

Change username with your currently logged in user, to see that execute this:

```
# whoami
```

Comment: Its able to read images from the storage. why not xls too?

Comment: you might uploaded it with your root user. send the output of this command
`ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/user_products.xlsx`

Comment: i have two storage directories here. i dont know how they got created. i am first creating the excel file, then i want it to be sent as attachment. upon `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/user_products.xlsx`. The output is `No such file or directory`

Comment: I copied it to that folder, the result is now.`ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/storage/user_products.xlsx                                         
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6556 Sep  5 16:49 /opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/storage/user_products.xlsx `

Comment: okay now execute this.
`sudo chown $USER:www-data -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/storage/user_products.xlsx`
`sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/RC/public/storage/user_products.xlsx`

Comment: awesome man. Its working. So in your answer you are syaing to change the permissions of htdocs? so everything inside it will have 755?

Comment: yeah. it might fix other unknown file permissions too. and as I said never give 777 permission on production. accepted anwser will be appreciated :).